# Can I use OpenID delegation with a standard Google account?

Tags: openid, gmail, delegation

I'm currently using ClaimID and have the following data on my website to allow delegation:

```
<link rel="openid.server" href="http://openid.claimid.com/server" />
<link rel="openid.delegate" href="http://openid.claimid.com/tjrobinson" />
```

Are there equivalent URLs for Google? If not, has there been any mention of support in future?

Before anyone marks this as a duplicate, I am aware of this existing question: [How do you delegate your OpenId to Google Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436829). However, that question refers specifically to Google Apps, I just want to know if I can use OpenID delegation with a normal @gmail.com account?

Comment: Is it still impossible? This was 6 months ago...

Answer (score 2):

Google does not support delegation.  If you search [the Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/google-federated-login-api) there are several threads, but they all reach the same conclusion: it's not supported at this time.

Comment: That's a shame, thanks anyway.

Comment: This answer is now outdated. See Rio's answer (and accompanying post). I'd consider accepting the other answer and/or removing this one.

Answer (score 0):

There is a value you could put into openid2.provider, but the problem is the openid2.local_id value... for Google, it assigns a different one to every RP. Which one would you put here? Until Google offers a non-anonymous claimed identifier, there's not much you can put here.

Oh, and of course the Provider on their end has to play by the rules of delegation, which I suspect it doesn't since it wouldn't be used since Google doesn't support it.