# Use Google Apps for Site Login?

Tags: php, oauth, google-apps

Hey all,
    I'm redesigning the infrastructure for a website, and I want to make the login system use the accounts on our Google Apps. How would I be able to do something like this? I'm using PHP for the backend.

Thanks for any help.
-Trey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OAuth is one way, but it might be easier to implement OpenID, which is already provided by Google Apps.  See [Google Apps domain as OpenID provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1203423/google-apps-domain-as-openid-provider)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Google Login PHP class](http://www.andrewpeace.com/php-google-login-class.html). It is no longer under active development and there is no support provided for it, but it should give you something to work off of. Also be sure to look [Google Federated Login](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OpenID.html) as a reference.