# OpenID and single sign on (sso)

Tags: single-sign-on, openid-provider

I have some some basic questions on Openid
1. Can anyone become an openid provider?
2. If someone signed-up to our site will they be able to use that id in any other website that uses open id ? example Google aps ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most sites that do OpenID are just consumers.  If you become a provider, you dictate who can become a consumer.  Many sites are only configured to accept specific OpenID providers, but those that accept any OpenID provider (e.g. SourceForge) will work with your provider.

For Google Apps, this post may be useful:

[How do you delegate your OpenId to Google Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436829/how-do-you-delegate-your-openid-to-google-apps)

Sounds like you have to pay Google money to get access to that feature but a lot can change in three years.

If you are just looking for a generic SSO system, I recommend looking at:

http://barebonescms.com/documentation/sso/

It is "consumer-only" for the moment.

Comment: can you give examples of sites that are restricted to certain IDPs? OpenID is about federation, so restricting the providers makes no sense.